# The named parameter 'bottomTitles' isn't defined

Tags: flutter

I'm getting the error "The named parameter 'bottomTitles' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'bottomTitles'." and "The named parameter 'leftTitles' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'leftTitles'."

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 300,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, right: 16, left: 16),
      child: BarChart(
        BarChartData(
          maxY: 20,
          titlesData: FlTitlesData(
            show: true,
            leftTitles: AxisTitles(
              bottomTitles: SideTitles(
              showTitles: true,
              margin: 20,
              getTitles: (double value) {
                switch (value.toInt()) {
                  case 0:
                    return 'Mn';
                  case 1:
                    return 'Te';
                  case 2:
                    return 'Wd';
                  case 3:
                    return 'Tu';
                  case 4:
                    return 'Fr';
                  case 5:
                    return 'St';
                  case 6:
                    return 'Sn';
                  default:
                    return '';
                }
              },
            ),

            leftTitles: SideTitles(
              showTitles: true,
              margin: 16,
              reservedSize: 14,
              getTitles: (value) {
                if (value == 0) {
                  return '100k';
                } else if (value == 10) {
                  return '20k';
                } else if (value == 19) {
                  return '25k';
                } else if (value == 5) {
                  return '14k';
                } else {
                  return '';
                }
              },
            ),
            )           
          ),
          borderData: FlBorderData(
            show: false,
          ),
          barGroups: showingBarGroups,
        ),
      ).center(),
    ).paddingAll(16).center();
  }
```

There were no quick fixes nor a typo so i didnt try anything

Comment: which package are you using?

Comment: these are the packages im using 
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nb_utils/nb_utils.dart';
import 'package:wallet_flutter/utils/WAColors.dart';

Comment: PLease include more code including `import` .

Comment: try the following answer if it is working for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have written the bottomTitles and leftTitles inside AxisTitles where it is not defined try this:

```dart
titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                          show: true,
                          leftTitles: AxisTitles(
                            sideTitles: SideTitles(
                              showTitles: true,
                              reservedSize: 14,
                              getTitlesWidget: (val, _) {
                                String titleText = "";

                                final int value = val.toInt();

                                if (value == 0) {
                                  titleText = '100k';
                                } else if (value == 10) {
                                  titleText = '20k';
                                } else if (value == 19) {
                                  titleText = '25k';
                                } else if (value == 5) {
                                  titleText = '14k';
                                } else {
                                  titleText = '';
                                }

                                return Text(
                                  titleText,
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
                            sideTitles: SideTitles(
                              showTitles: true,
                              getTitlesWidget: (double value, _) {
                                switch (value.toInt()) {
                                  case 0:
                                    return Text('Mn');
                                  case 1:
                                    return Text('Te');
                                  case 2:
                                    return Text('Wd');
                                  case 3:
                                    return Text('Tu');
                                  case 4:
                                    return Text('Fr');
                                  case 5:
                                    return Text('St');
                                  case 6:
                                    return Text('Sn');
                                  default:
                                    return Text('');
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                          )),
```